# Will email address obfuscation code that could look like it might be malicious hurt search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, email-address, code

I use an email obfuscation tool.

`<a href="mailto:email@domain.tld">Send email</a>`

would become:

`<span class="noscript"><span>&#83;&#101;&#110;</span><span>&#100;&#32;&#101;</span><em class="random" >hmrfk</em><span>&#109;&#97;</span><span>&#105;&#108;</span><code style='display:none;' >nlxz</code> (<span>&#101;&#109;</span><span>&#97;&#105;</span><a style='display: none;' >fk</a><span>&#108;&#64;&#100;</span><span>&#111;&#109;&#97;</span><span>&#105;&#110;&#46;&#116;</span><span>&#108;&#100;</span><i style='display:none;' >zw2</i>)</span><script type='text/javascript'>document.write('<a' + ' href="');var bc='mai';var ogkg='lto:';var dkkh='emai';var gk='l@';var dxe='dom';var xr='ain';var ublu='.t';var lboy='ld';document.write(bc+ogkg+dkkh+gk+dxe+xr+ublu+lboy+'');document.write('"  >');var lyjw='Sen';var mix='d em';var mz='ail';document.write(lyjw+mix+mz+'');document.write(endATag);</script>`

Will the site get ranked down because the indexer sees what looks like malicious code, but is not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the google crawler has no concept of "obfuscated code". Many sites minify their code for legit reasons, and don't run into any issues with ranking or indexing.

That being said, expect Google to run your JavaScript when it crawls your page. This may cause the deobfuscated email address to show up in Google's cache, which may not be a concern, but it's something to be aware of.

I can't speak for other search engines, but I highly doubt that any of them would penalize you for this either.

Comment: Worth noting that, if Google can run your JavaScript, so can any other crawler. OP, have you any empirical evidence that this sort of obfuscation actually works?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I read an article a long time back that showed it helps a lot, at least back then. Spammers are not persistent criminals, like other types. Generally you don't need to have good security to deter them, just slightly better security than the next website over. Like the parable about outrunning the bear and whatnot.

Comment: Sure, that principle makes sense, but in 2020 I'm not entirely convinced it's worth the effort, without some data